# Dump ERP queries in informix

Tags: sql, database, delphi, odbc, informix

We have a closed source application here, that connect to an informix database ( using odbc )
is there any way I can see the queries being executed by this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on ODBC tracing. Some information can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple possibilities :
those give all the statements

- like mentioned above odbc tracing.
- set explain on as pre sql (generates huge files with the sqls and query plans).

those the current running statements.

- using onstat commands on the server running the database (onstat -g sql ).
- connecting to the monitoring database (sysmonitor) and querying the session tables .